# Meaning of "two days either side of a dash" (from a motivational speech)

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms, idiom-meaning

There is a motivational speech which I'm having trouble understanding. Here's the phrase:

> There are two days either side of a dash, make sure that dash is not empty.

What's the meaning of it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an obscure cultural reference, not an established idiomatic usage that would be recognised by many native Anglophones. To me it also sounds a bit unnatural to use ***days*** there rather than ***dates***, even though I've never encountered *either* version before this question.

Comment: Can you provide more of the original text? It seems it's saying to make sure there are other days in between two days he's given you. Like do something for more than just two days in a row?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that this isn't a widely known English idiom, but I don't agree that it is *all* that obscure (I also agree re *dates* vs *days*). I have heard *at least the idea* (if not the exact phrase) many times in my life, in church sermons and such.

Comment: @BradC: Now I'm really intrigued. As I said, it seems to me that ***dates*** should be much more likely that ***days*** in such a context, so my first thought on seeing this question was that it looks like a "homily" badly translated from some language other than English. Can you provide any supporting references for the idea that this usage was "coined" by a native speaker (or indeed, has any currency)? For what it's worth, I can say that Google Books contains no instances at all of the specific text ***make sure that dash is not empty***.

Comment: We don't have a migration path for it, but IMHO this question belongs on [SE Puzzling](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), not ELU.

Comment: Searching for "sermon make the dash count" returns many on-topic results, including [a 1996 poem](http://www.linda-ellis.com/the-dash-the-dash-poem-by-linda-ellis-.html), a [philanthropic organization](http://www.makethedashcount.org/) of the same name, and many church-specific pages or sermons. See also "living the dash" and "the dash between the dates". Most results are in the religious/inspirational community.

Comment: Arguably this question is about an uncommon meaning of the word "dash". The number of Google hits suggest the usage is sufficiently established to justify its legitimacy, at which point this question is most assuredly on topic.

Comment: @ArtB It's the typical definition of the word "dash", its just employing its use in one particular context as a motivational allegory. Of course, the speaker should have explained the tombstone context, and perhaps they did earlier in the talk. Pastors frequently also make references to prior sermons/lessons that only regular attendees may understand.

Answer (score 40):

It's an allegorical reference to a tombstone inscription:

[image: Jimmy Stewart's Tombstone]

Between the date of your birth and the date of your death is all the rest of your life, represented visually by the **dash between the dates** on the tombstone.

It is encouraging you to "*make your life matter*".

This phrase itself isn't an English idiom, per se, but the allegory is widely known in the religious/inspirational community.

[This tweet](https://twitter.com/fearlessmotivat/status/764886090989744128?lang=en) may be the version that you heard (thanks, @mahmudkoya), which makes more grammatical sense than your original quote:

> One day it will be over. There will be 2 dates, either side of a dash. Make sure that dash is not empty.
>   [- Fearless Motivation](https://twitter.com/fearlessmotivat/status/764886090989744128?lang=en)

Some further references and variations:

- [**The Dash**](http://www.linda-ellis.com/the-dash-the-dash-poem-by-linda-ellis-.html), a 1996 poem by Linda Ellis.
- [**Make the Dash Count**](http://www.makethedashcount.org/), a faith-based philanthropic organization.
- [**The Dash Between The Dates**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014T164WI) - Album by American singer/songwriter Maia Sharp.
- [**Living the Dash**](http://www.oleantrinity.com/hp_wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/OMTL-4.15.12.pdf) (PDF link) - A example of how this might be used in a local church.
- Urban Dictionary Entry for **[Live the Dash](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=live%20the%20dash)**.

Comment: Outstanding catch and outstandingly sleek answer.

Comment: Thanks, @YosefBaskin. The exact phrase itself might not be a widely known idiom per se, but it is a very common sermon illustration, and I've heard it many times in my life.

Comment: "One day it will be over. There will be 2 dates, either side of a dash. Make sure that dash is not empty."https://twitter.com/fearlessmotivat/status/764886090989744128?lang=en

Comment: Well done! That comma before "either" is essential (see @mahmudkoya's [comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/376196/meaning-of-two-days-either-side-of-a-dash-from-a-motivational-speech#comment882215_376198)). Otherwise, there are 4 days / dates in total, two on the left and two on the right. I've taken the liberty of adding mahmud's find into your answer together with the 2 dates vs 4 days note. Please feel free to roll it back or to edit it further if you wish.

Comment: @Lawrence I like the quote, especially since it fixes the grammar in the original question. I'll just blend it in a little more.